# C# IList content to Excel Sheet?

Tags: c#

I have my DB table contents in IList. Now i need to copy from IList to Excel sheet. Is there any solution? Thanks in ADV.

Answer (score 1):

This looks interesting too, I think:

[Open XML Package Editor Power Tool for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b)

> Open XML Package Editor Power Tool for Visual Studio 2010
>
> This Power Tool is a Visual Studio add-in that provides an easy way to
>   parse and edit Open Packaging Conventions files, including Word, Excel
>   and PowerPoint documents. This Power Tool enables you to do the
>   following tasks:
>
> - Open any Open XML Package file or XPS Package file directly in Visual Studio 2010
> - Browse the contents of Package files in a tree view
> - Open any XML part directly in Visual Studio's rich XML editor
> - Add or remove parts and relationships directly in the user interface
> - Import and export part contents to and from files
> - Detect when a Package file that is opened in Visual Studio is modified externally. The Power Tool prompts user to reload the file
>     without having to close any open XML part editors
> - Create new Office Packages from a set of templates using Visual Studio's File > New dialog